# How to send data(books) of particular genre from one module to another module in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to show books of particular genre in angular when I click on that genre. I have a list of all the genres in a module, and when I click to a particular genre, I want all the books, associated to that genre, to another module. I'm receiving the books in console when I click on a genre, but I want to show those books in angular front end. And I have no idea how to send/show books related to a particular genre on another module when I click to that particular genre. **Please explain and answer the question by editing/implementing in the code.**

**genres.component.ts file. Here is the function get_books_of_single_genre(name: Genres), to get books**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
import { Book } from '../books/bookschema';
import { Genres } from './genres_schema';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-genres',
  templateUrl: './genres.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./genres.component.css'],
})
export class GenresComponent implements OnInit {
  GenreForm = new FormGroup({
    _id: new FormControl(''),
    name: new FormControl(''),
    floor: new FormControl(''),
    genre_number: new FormControl(''),
    shelves: new FormControl(''),
  });
  results?: Genres[];
  bookresults?: Book[];

constructor(private readonly apiService: ApiService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.model = this.apiService.getallgenres().subscribe((data) => {
      this.results = data;
      console.log(this.results);
    });
  }
  async get_books_of_single_genre(name: Genres) {
    (await this.apiService.getallBooksofSingleGenere(name)).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.bookresults = data;
        console.log(data);
      }
    );
    }
```

**genre.component.htnml. Here is the div where I'm executing the function. And when I click on the function it gets the data(books) from mongodb using http request on console, of the particular genre and the routerLink is for to move to the next module which is SinglegenreBooks. And I want that, when I click on this function it will not just move to next module but also show/send those books in that module.**

```
<div class="grid" *ngFor="let result of results">
    <div class="blog-card spring-fever">
      <div class="title-content">
        <h3>
          <a href="#">{{ result?.name }}</a>
        </h3>
        <div class="intro"><a href="#">Inspiration</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-info">
        <a
          href="#"
          (click)="get_books_of_single_genre(result)"
          routerLink="/singlegenrebooks"
          >Enter<span class="licon icon-arr icon-black"></span
        ></a>
```

**singlegenrebooks.component.ts. Here I want to implement the logic to receive the data(books) which are showing in console after clicking on the function in previous module.**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/api.service';
import { Book } from 'src/app/books/bookschema';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sinlegenrebooks',
  templateUrl: './sinlegenrebooks.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sinlegenrebooks.component.css'],
})
export class SinlegenrebooksComponent implements OnInit {
  SingleGenreBookForm = new FormGroup({
    _id: new FormControl(''),
    bid: new FormControl(''),
    name: new FormControl(''),
    author: new FormControl(''),
    price: new FormControl(''),
    genres_name: new FormControl(''),
  });
  results?: Book[];
  searchedText: string = '';
  model: any;

  constructor(
    private readonly apiService: ApiService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  async ngOnInit() {}
}
```

**singlegenrebooks.component.html. Html page where all the books will be available at front end. I tried something in html but it is not correct. I hope to get a Solution and I will be able to show the data at angular front end**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div
    class="container-fluid"
    style="
      background-image: url('https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/new-templates/search-box/img4.jpg');
    "
  >
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WC Library</a>
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="text"
      data-bs-toggle="collapse"
      data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            class="nav-link active"
            aria-current="page"
            href="#"
            routerLink=""
            routerLinkActive="GenresComponent"
            >Home</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            class="nav-link active"
            aria-current="page"
            href="#"
            routerLink="/books"
            routerLinkActive="GenresComponent"
            >Books</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            class="nav-link"
            aria-current="page"
            href="#"
            routerLink="/genres"
            routerLinkActive="BooksComponent"
            >Genres</a
          >
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a
            class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
            href="#"
            id="navbarDropdown"
            role="button"
            data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
            aria-expanded="false"
          >
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider" /></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input
          class="form-control me-2"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search Book by Name"
          aria-label="Search"
          [(ngModel)]="searchedText"
          name="name"
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="background">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <button
      style="margin-top: 1%"
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg gradient-custom-4 text-body"
      routerLink="/"
    >
      Go Back
    </button>
    <button
      style="margin-left: 60%; margin-top: 1%"
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg gradient-custom-4 text-body"
      routerLink="/adbooksroute"
    >
      Add Books
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="grid" *ngFor="let result of results">
    <div class="blog-card spring-fever">
      <div class="title-content">
        <h3>
          <a href="#">{{ result?.name }}</a>
        </h3>
        <div class="intro">
          <h5>
            <a>Author<b>:</b>&nbsp;{{ result?.author }}</a>
          </h5>

          <h5>
            <a>Price<b>:</b>&nbsp;Rs{{ result?.price }}</a>
          </h5>
          <h5>
            <a>Genre<b>:</b>&nbsp;{{ result?.genres_name }}</a>
          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-info">
        <button
          style="
            margin-top: 2%;
            margin-left: 2%;
            margin-bottom: 5%;
            height: 45px;
            width: 100px;
            text-align: center;
          "
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg gradient-custom-4 text-body"
        >
          <h5 style="color: whitesmoke">Update</h5>
        </button>
        <button
          style="
            margin-top: 2%;
            margin-left: 2%;
            margin-bottom: 5%;
            height: 45px;
            width: 100px;
            text-align: center;
          "
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-success btn-block btn-lg gradient-custom-4 text-body"
        >
          <h5 style="color: whitesmoke">Delete</h5>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="utility-info">
        <ul class="utility-list">
          <li><span class="licon icon-like"></span><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><span class="licon icon-com"></span><a href="#">12</a></li>
          <li><span class="licon icon-dat"></span>03 jun 2017</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="gradient-overlay"></div>
      <div class="color-overlay"></div>
      <!-- /.blog-card -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How I would do this, is to when user clicks a genre, then navigate to a page with the id (or something else unique) and **there** fetch the books belonging to that genre. Just check the official documentation at angular io on the tour of heroes tutorial how it is done. If you don't want to do it that way, then communicating with service would be the best option in my opinion: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-using-a-service

Comment: @AT82 thanks for giving me hint man. The issue is solved. What I did is that, I made `setter and getter` functions in my `service file with the type of genre`. Than I sent the info of clicked genre to the second module with `setter function`, and received the values in the `second module's ngOnInIt with a getter function`, and also run the function in ngOnInIt which `fetches the particular books`. And made two `FormGroups` one for books and second for Genre(needed to receive values) and returned the Genre values as parameter in the function`get_books_of_single_genre(this.GenreForm.value)`.